# what is the Best way to optimize MySQL join with to much registers

Tags: mysql

I created a basic point of sale what increase to much and I'm having some problems with the optimization...

I have 2 tables **sales** and **earnings**

Both of them have the field **ticket** and that's how I do the join but it takes more than 25 seconds

The reason for the join its the table **sales** does't have a field of date or something to group per month, now I know that was a bad decision, so I have to group by the field date on the table **earnings**

It its possible optimize this query ?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS total   
FROM sales s
JOIN earnings e
ON s.ticket = e.ticket
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%Y-%m-01')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%Y-%m-01') DESC
```

Comment: You could consider adding an index on one/both of the `ticket` join columns.  Beyond this, I don't see much room for improvement, because `COUNT(*)` will have to touch every record in order to get the count.

Comment: How do you know which count belongs to which yearmonth!?!